# Find the specific day of a given month and given year

Tags: perl-module

is there a Perl module which could give me for input month and year, let say, 06-2005, what the last day of this month for this year is? For this example, it is easy, because June always has 30 days, so the last day will be 30-06-2005. But it is not the case for February. So, if I have 02-1997, I would like to know whether to return 28-02-1997 or 29-02-1997. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at the [DateTime](http://datetime.perl.org) project.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a subroutine `Days_in_Month` in the `Date::Calc` module.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Date::Calc qw/Days_in_Month/;

for my $m (1 .. 12) {
  print Days_in_Month(2005, $m), "\n";
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
31
28
31
30
31
30
31
31
30
31
30
31
```

Answer (score 0):

The last day in a given month is the "0th" day of the following month. mktime() takes a 0-based month and 1900-based year number, and returns an epoch timestamp.

```
use POSIX qw( mktime strftime );

sub last_day {
   my ( $year, $mon ) = @_;
   return mktime(0,0,0, 0, $mon, $year-1900);
}
```

You can pass that to `localtime` or `strftime`.

```
say scalar localtime last_day(2005, 5)
'Tue May 31 00:00:00 2005'

say scalar localtime last_day(2005, 6)
'Thu Jun 30 00:00:00 2005'

say scalar localtime last_day(1997, 2)
'Fri Feb 28 00:00:00 1997'

say scalar localtime last_day(2012, 2)
'Wed Feb 29 00:00:00 2012'

say (localtime last_day(1997, 2))[3]
'28'

say strftime "%d", localtime last_day(1997, 2)
'28'
```

Answer (score 0):

As others said, use [`DateTime`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime):

```
use DateTime;
my $dt = DateTime->last_day_of_month('year'=>2000, 'month'=>2);
print $dt->ymd; # '2000-02-29'
```

While DateTime may not be the fastest module for handling dates/times, it's definitely the most complete one. It's also the only one that handles the various quirks of date/time math correctly.